# Number of spanning trees for this graph

Tags: graph-theory

Find $\tau(G)$ for the graph $G$ below.

[image]

This is what I tried so far:
Let $e$ denote the horizontal edge between the two vertices as shown below. I wanted to use $\tau(G) = \tau(G-e) + \tau(G \circ e)$

$(G \circ e)$ denotes the contraction of edge $e$.

I got 4 as the answer. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, and in this simple case, you can just look at the graph. There are exactly four edges that can be deleted without disconnecting the graph (those on the $4$-cycle), and once you delete any of these, you get a spanning tree.

Comment: Yes.  You can also see this visually.  There is only one cycle, and there are $4$ ways to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the upper two vertices to be connected to the remaining vertices, the two edges incident to them must be chosen.   The remaining part of the graph is a 4-cycle and we need to obtain a spanning tree on these four vertices. Here any one of the four edges in the cycle can be removed.  Thus the graph has 4 spanning trees.